# Evernote Note filesize

Tags: database, evernote

I wonder if there is an option (inside of Evernote or outside of it, manually with the help of 3rd party tools) to locate the biggest notes inside of Evernote? I want to remove those or put them into another system. Basically a "order after note(file) size" option is what I need.

My EN database is now over 250 MB big due to my increased usage so I need to take some action.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within Evernote, if you go to *all Notes* and you're in *list view* you should have the header **size**. If not, right click and select it to be visible. You can then sort by size of note.

[image]

Comment: Evernote also has a drop-down (visible in your screenshot!) called [sort] "Notes by..." (size, in this case), which does the same even when you not have the "list" view activated, but the "snippet" or the "thumbnail" view.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using an evernote clone called nevernote on ubuntu, in my case the database used is [H2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_%28DBMS%29). It is possible to connect to the database using web interface, and run SQL queries as explained [here](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_server).

Comment: I totally don't get how this is relatd to my question or how this is a practical solution for non-SQL-nerds..."Raystafarian" did luckily answer this one.

Comment: Sry grunwald2.0, this was the only solution I could think of.